# LINQ to Dataset SELECT NOT IN to a table?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, linq

Here is my working LINQ to dataset query.  I have added a fourth table and I want to add a NOT IN type filter to the query where query1.dedpk NOT IN deduct.dedpk.  Not sure how to do it.

```
  var main = dsTemp.Tables["Maindata"].AsEnumerable();
  var pg = dsTemp.Tables["pgto"].AsEnumerable();
  var py = dsTemp.Tables["pyto"].AsEnumerable();
  var deduct = dsTemp.Tables["Deduct"].AsEnumerable();

  var query1 = from mainrow in main
      join pgrow in pg on mainrow.Field<string>("pgpk") equals pgrow.Field<string>("pgpk")
      join pyrow in py on mainrow.Field<string>("pypk") equals pyrow.Field<string>("pypk")
      into griddata 
      select new
       {
       lastname = mainrow.Field<string>("lastname"),
       firstname = mainrow.Field<string>("firstname"),
 dedpk = mainrow.Field<string>("dedpk"),
        };
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you want all `dedpk` fields or the complete rows? The former is easier using `Enumerable.Except`, the latter would be a linq left outer join.

Comment: There are no rows in deduct that I want.  It is just a pk exclusion list.  All the rows I need are in the main table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 var query1 = from mainrow in main
      join pgrow in pg on mainrow.Field<string>("pgpk") equals pgrow.Field<string>("pgpk")
      join pyrow in py on mainrow.Field<string>("pypk") equals pyrow.Field<string>("pypk")
      into griddata 
      where 
         !deduct.Any(x => x.Field<string>("dedpk") == mainrow.Field<string>("dedpk"))
      select new
      {
         lastname = mainrow.Field<string>("lastname"),
         firstname = mainrow.Field<string>("firstname"),
         dedpk = mainrow.Field<string>("dedpk"),
      };
```